# Answer to problem doesn't match WolframAlpha - what's the correct solution?

Tags: calculus

> Reference for people who search in future: Problem 8 of George
>   Simmons' *Calculus with Analytic Geometry*, pg. 57

### Find the equations of the two lines through the point $(3,1)$ that are tangent to the curve $y = x^2 - 4$.

This is how I tried to solve it:

$$
\begin{align}
y &= x^2 -4 \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 2x \\
\text{Let the point of tangency be } &(a, a^2 -4) \text{. Then:} \\
y - (a^2 - 4) &= 2a(x-a) \\
y - a^2 + 4 &= 2ax - 2a^2 \\
y &= -a^2 + 2ax -4 \\
\text{At point } &(3,1) : \\
1 &= -a^2 +2a\cdot3 -4 \\
a^2 -6a +5 &= 0 \\
(a-1)(a-5) &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$
So, the two points of tangency are: $(1,-3)$ and $(5,21)$. Thus we get the equations:

At point $(1,-3)$:
$$
\begin{align}
y +3 &= 2(x-1) \\
y &= 2x - 5
\end{align}
$$

And for point of tangency $(5,21)$ : 
$$
\begin{align}
y -21 &= 10(x-5) \\
y &= 10x - 29
\end{align}
$$

---

The Output from [WolframAlpha is this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+to+the+curve+y+%3D+x%5E2+-+4+that+passes+through+(3,1)). Specifically, it states that the point of tangency is **(1,-3)**, thus generating only one equation:

$$y=2x-5$$

[image: Wolfram Alpha output]

---

So, what's the correct procedure, and why didn't WolframAlpha show the second equation?

Comment: Your work is correct, and your answer is correct. Wolfram missed the other tangent line. You should request a refund!

Comment: If you change the "Slope-intercept form" into something else you can get the second equation. Sadly it still isn't the right equation though.